# Quick Book Integration in rails with 0Auth2 says The redirect_uri query parameter value is invalid

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Trying to integrate quick Book integration in rails.
Followed this github code https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby/tree/389-oauth2

Gemfile used

```
gem 'quickbooks-ruby'
gem 'oauth2'
```

my routes

```
 resources :vendors do
  collection do 
    get :authenticate
    get :oauth_callback
  end
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<body>
<!-- REPLACE THE BODY of the default application.html.erb with this -->

<% unless session[:token] %>
  <ipp:connectToIntuit></ipp:connectToIntuit>
<% end %>

<% if notice %>
  <div style="padding: 10px;background: gainsboro;font-weight: 900;width: 50%;"><%= notice %></div>
<% end %>

<%= yield %>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js"></script>

<script>
    intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({menuProxy: '/path/to/blue-dot', grantUrl: '<%= authenticate_vendors_url %>'});
</script>
```

controller code

```
 def authenticate
  #redirect_uri = authenticate_vendors_path
   redirect_uri = "http://localhost:3000#{authenticate_vendors_path}"
  grant_url = ::QB_OAUTH2_CONSUMER.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => redirect_uri, :response_type => "code", :state => SecureRandom.hex(12), :scope => "com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting")
  redirect_to grant_url
end
    
      def oauth_callback
        redirect_uri = oauth_callback_vendors_url
          if resp = ::QB_OAUTH2_CONSUMER.auth_code.get_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => redirect_uri)
        at = session[:qb_request_token].get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier])
      quickbooks_credentials.update_attributes(access_token: resp.token, refresh_token: resp.refresh_token, realm_id: params[:realmId])

      end
```

config/initializers/quickbook.rb

```
    QB_KEY = "mykey here"
QB_SECRET = "mysecrect here"


oauth_params = {
  :site => "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2",
  :authorize_url => "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2",
  :token_url => "https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer"
}

::QB_OAUTH2_CONSUMER = OAuth2::Client.new(QB_KEY,QB_SECRET, oauth_params)
Quickbooks.sandbox_mode = true
```

Getting this error when i try to click with quickbooks button

[image]

No idea about what is the error in my code.
Any help is appreciatable.

Comment: I guess that `redirect_uri` for your `authenticate` action controller is not the same as the one you have configured in your quickbooks account. Also, most likely you should use `authenticate_vendors_url` instead of `authenticate_vendors_path` because that should determine if you're in localhost, production or any other env.

Comment: modified redirect_uri to vendors_url, and now it is working